# Q[x,y]/(x) = Q[y]?

Tags: ring-theory

I tried to use R[x]/I =(R/I)[x] to prove it and somewhat done. The thing is tho i'd like to see how it should be written formally and how to interpret terms such as (Q[y])[x]/ (x) provided it is correct.

Due to my poor understanding of ring theory in general, please explain as elementary and baic you could.

Comment: $k[x,y]/(x) \simeq k[t]$ By isomorphism:
$\phi:[y] \mapsto t$.
$\phi^{-1}: t\mapsto y$
I'm sorry if i understand u incorrectly

Answer (score 3):

For any commutative ring $\,R\,$ we have $\,R[x]/(x) \cong R.\,$ Indeed the evaluation hom $\,R[x]\to R\,$ via $\,x\mapsto 0\,$ has kernel $\,(x),\,$ since $\,f(0)=0\iff x\mid f(x)\,$ by the Factor Theorem.

Yours is the special case $\, R = Q[y],\,$ since $,Q[x,y]\cong (Q[y])[x].$

Comment: thanks, this is what i wanted, but how should I interpret (Q[y])[x]/(x) in a meaningful way?

Comment: @AR92 $\ $ As above, the isomorphism between $\,R[x]/(x)\,$ and $R\,$ arises by evaluation at $\,x=0.\,$ You can think of it as doing polynomial arithmetic but ignoring all but the constant terms. As an analogy: for integers, we can compute the units digit in decimal arithmetic by calculating mod $\,10,\,$ ignoring all non-unit digits.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, probably, is to define $f:R[x,y]\rightarrow R[y]$ by $f|_{R[y]} = \text{id}_{R[y]}$ and $x\mapsto 0$. You can check that this is a homomorphism. Next we check that the kernel of this map is $(x)$, so that our result follows by the first isomorphism theorem. Note that $f(x) = 0$, so $(x)\subseteq\ker(f)$. Next, choose $\alpha\in R[x,y]$ and suppose $f(\alpha) = 0$. Define $\tilde{\alpha}$ as the polynomial $\alpha$ with all factors that contain $x$ removed. Then $\tilde{\alpha}\in R[y]$ and $f(\alpha) = f(\tilde\alpha) = \tilde\alpha$. Thus $f(\alpha)=0$ iff $\tilde\alpha=0$ iff $\alpha\in(x)$. We conclude that $\ker(f)\subseteq(x)$, which concludes the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The universal property of free $R$-algebras tells you you can define a map $R[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \to A$ (where $A$ is also an $R$-algebra) by simply saying where the elements $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ get mapped to ; then you extend by "polynomiality" (in the same way that in the theory of vector spaces, you map the elements of a basis and then you "extend by linearity").

Thus if you want to define a map $R[x,y]/(x) \to R[t]$, this is equivalent to defining a map $R[x,y] \to R[t]$ with kernel containing $(x)$ ; so just send $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $t$, which gives you a map $R[x,y]/(x) \to R[t]$. Using the universal property again, you get a map $R[t] \to R[x,y]/(x)$ by sending $t$ to the equivalence class of $y$ in the quotient ring. Now you have two maps and you can easily check that they are inverse of each other ($t \longleftrightarrow y+(x)$), hence you have your isomorphism.

Otherwise, the trick $R[x,y]/(x) \simeq (R[x])[y]/(x) \simeq (R[x]/(x))[y] \simeq R[y]$ works too, but at each step you have a (trivial) isomorphism to check. It's up to you to choose where you like to work.

Hope that helps,

Comment: thanks a lot for answering and going to details, I think it should be (R[y])[x]/(x) though.

Comment: @AR92 : I was using $R[x]/IR[x] \simeq (R/I)[x]$, where $I$ is generated by elements of $R$. To get this isomorphism, note that the map $R[x] \to (R/I)[x]$ sending $x$ to $x$ is a well-defined map of $R$-algebras with $IR[x]$ in its kernel, so you get a well-defined map $R[x]/IR[x] \to (R/I)[x]$. Then you just check it is an isomorphism by hand or something.