# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y] $ / (X) is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

This particular question was asked in a masters entrance exam .

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y] $ / (X) is a PID  .

I will not be able to show any attempt because I dont know how I should start and also due to the fact these type of questions were not given in the assignments given to us in the class .

Kindly shed some light on this question .

Comment: Isn't $\Bbb Q[X,Y]/(X)$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[Y]$?

Comment: Do you think that ring might be isomorphic to a more well-known ring that could be easier to work with?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177393/qx-y-x-qy).

Comment: @GregMartin Yes  thanks .

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks I got the solution .